# How to find other HTML color codes?

Tags: html

What is the HTML color code for Infra-Red and Ultra-Violet? 
I have tried "#FF0000+\n" and "#800080!" but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Do you mean how to look up color codes? Like http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

Comment: Aren’t both “colors” of invisible wavelength?

Comment: @dakab: Invisible to humans anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to get mixed results anywhere you look. So it's really up to you what color you think is closest and looks best.

[rgb.to](http://rgb.to) returns `#330099` for [Ultra-Violet](http://rgb.to/color/18038/ultraviolet) and doesn't have a code for Infrared.

[colorhexa](http://www.colorhexa.com/) returns `#ff3333` for [Infrared](http://www.colorhexa.com/ff2247) but its actual name is Vivid Red.

*Note: The color codes are the web-safe colors, the hex codes are different.*

As Justin mentioned in the comments, to find other color codes there are numerous tools available.

- [Adobe Color](http://color.adobe.com/)
- [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)